# Working For Chocolate

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

#### NEW JOB!

Congratulations on your new job. Times are tough in the economy, so you agree to be paid in chocolate.

[image: Chocolate Bar]

### Compensation Package

Each week the boss buys a chocolate bar, evenly split into 7 pieces, to cover your salary.

|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|

For each day's work, you will be paid one piece of chocolate.

### Cut It Out!

For reasons we don't know, the boss can only make TWO cuts out of your chocolate bar. If he/she can only make 2 cuts in the bar, can you figure out a way to make the cuts so you  get paid exactly one chocolate piece every day?

Comment: Simple, break the rest of with your fingers :P

Comment: Ha ! Well, the boss can't do that. Only two cuts, and from those pieces, figure out how to pay the employee one piece per day. That was thinking outside the box though!

Comment: rot13(Vg vf jbegu abgvat gung gur pbeerpg fbyhgvba phgf gur one vagb cvrprf bs bar, gjb, naq sbhe, juvpu znxrf nal qnl sebz bar gb frira rkcerffvoyr va ovanel.)
EDIT: Huh, that's weird, I used both "one" and "bar", which are rot13 pairs, in the same comment.

Comment: This question is not the same.  If you apply that sort of criteria, then all mathematical algebra equation question that use a similar formula would be excluded. That makes no sense at all.  So all permutation questions should be excluded because one permutation question will clearly explain how it works, so why bother posting the others?  Do you see how your rational does not make any sense? I just looked at a puzzle that uses logic deduction grid.  So why are the other hundred of logic deduction grids still on there? They are worded differently, but use the same mathematical reasoning. Bias.